# reactjs react-sticky for fixed/sticky header not working

Tags: reactjs

I want to use [react-sticky](https://github.com/captivationsoftware/react-sticky) to create my header and footer component.

App.js:

```
class App extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <Header />
                    <SomeContent />
                </div>
            );
        }
}
```

Header.js:

```
class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <StickyContainer>
                <Sticky>
                    <header>
                        <h1>Header</h1>
                    </header>
                </Sticky>
            </StickyContainer>
        );
    }
}
```

SomeContent.js:

```
class SomeContent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var style = {
            width: '100%',
            height: '1500px',
            border: '1px solid red'
        }
        return(
            <div style={style}>
                <p>Lorem</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The page is displaying App.js including both Header and SomeContent. However if I scroll down, the Header is not sticky/fixed in its position. It moves up like any normal div. Where am I missing? Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure wether it's not too late, but i believe that you put StickyContainer in the wrong place. So for your example it should be smth like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <StickyContainer>
                    <Header />
                    <SomeContent />
                </StickyContainer>
            );
        }
}
```

and

```
class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
                <Sticky>
                    <header>
                        <h1>Header</h1>
                    </header>
                </Sticky>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Sticky component provides some props to the child components therefore your header.js should be. Where style is a regular style object calculated by `react-sticky`

```
class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <StickyContainer>
        <Sticky>
          {({
            style,
          }) => (
            <header style={style}>
              <h1>Header</h1>
            </header>
          )}
        </Sticky>
      </StickyContainer>
    );
  }
}
```